# how do i read a value from a text field and do some calculation and write the result back to another text field in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

here is my javascript code. I want to get the results from multiplying sum1 * sum2 and then read that results and perform 1% on it and put the answer in text field premium.

```
function suma(){
        var sum1 = document.getElementById("sum1");
        var sum2 = document.getElementById("sum2");
        var input = document.getElementById("results");
        results = (sum1.value * sum2.value);
        input.value= results;
    }
    function percentage(){
        var results = document.getElementById("results");
        var input = document.getElementById("premium");
        var premium1 = 0.01*results.value;
        document.getElementById("premium").value=premium1;
    }
```

here is my html code

```
<div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
    <label class="text-primary"><strong><?php echo $PesoKg; ?>&nbsp;(<?php 
    echo $_SESSION['ge_measure']; ?>)<strong></label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" required onblur="if(this.value 
    == ''){this.value='0'}" onKeyUp="suma();"  id="sum2"   name="Weight" 
    value="0" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
    <label class="text-primary"><strong>Amt&nbsp;<?php echo $PrimerKilo; ? 
    >&nbsp;<?php echo $_SESSION['ge_measure']; ?><strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" onblur="if(this.value == '') 
    {this.value='0'}"  onKeyUp="suma();" id="sum1"    name="variable" 
    value="3.25" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
    <label class="text-primary"><strong><?php echo $SubtotalEnvio; ?><strong> 
    </i></label>
    <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="shipping_subtotal" 
    id="results" value="0" />
    </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
    <label class="text-primary"><strong>Insurance 1%<strong></label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control"  id="insurance" 
    name="insurance" required onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='0'}" 
    onKeyUp= "percentage();" name="variable" value="0.01" >
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
    <label class="text-primary"><strong>Premium<strong></label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control"  id="premium" name="premium" 
    value="0" >
    </div>
```

how do i get the value of results and calculate 1% on that results and put the answer in the text field premium. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Please go read [ask], and then edit your question with a description of what actual _problem_ you are having implementing this. (Only stating what you “want” is not a proper way of asking questions on this site.)

Comment: Take result, divide it by 100, you have 1%, put it where you need it.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the clarification. I'm new on here so please bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can read a value from a text field and do some calculation and write the result back.
You can find great javascript/jquery tutorials [here](https://www.w3schools.com)

```js
function calculatePercentage(){
  // getting the input value;
  var value = $('#input').val();
  
  // calculating 1% 
  var percentage = value * 0.01;
  
  //writing the result
  $('#result').val(percentage);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form action="" >
    <label> value: </label>
    <input type='number' value='' id='input' name='input'/>
    <button onclick='calculatePercentage()'>calculate 1%</button>
    <br><br>
    <label> Result: </label>
    <input type='number' id='result' />
  </form>
</div>
```